# Titanium 2 : get image size?

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I use Titanium. I test with an Android nexus S.

I've got a blob which is a photo from the gallery. I can't find a way to get the width and height of this photo.

I've seen some tips with the auto property but this tip seems to not run **since titanium 2.0**.

---

### First try

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success : function(e) {
        alert(e.media.width + " x " + e.media.height);
}});
```

***Result "0 x 0"***

---

### Second try

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success : function(e) {
        var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    image : e.media, 
                    width: 'auto', 
                    height: 'auto' });
        alert(img.width + " x " + img.height);
}});
```

***Result "auto x auto"***

---

So, my simple question:

**How can I get size of a photo obtained from the gallery ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another few tries (during the wrote of this question), I've found it:

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success : function(e) {
        var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    image : e.media, 
                    width: 'auto', 
                    height: 'auto' });
        alert(img.toImage().width + " x " + img.toImage().height);
}});
```

the tip is to use img.toImage().width